# Come tradurre “othering” in italiano?

Tags: translation

Trovo il verbo inglese *to other* e l'espression *othering* molto utili per parlare di questioni di sociologia e psicologia. Rappresenta il processo di rendere un'altra persona o un altro gruppo ["altri", in senso filosofico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Other_(philosophy)).

> *Part of the process of “**othering**” is to dehumanise those we perceive as different, unfamiliar, or a threat to our own sense of self.* - da [questo articolo](https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/commentisfree/2021/may/07/have-australians-in-india-been-abandoned-because-people-of-colour-are-seen-as-less-australian) sul Guardian

> *Oxford's 'students of colour' on being **'othered'** at university* - dal [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/education/shortcuts/2014/mar/12/oxford-university-students-of-colour-being-othered)

> *Bernadine Evaristo talks womanhood and '**othering**'* - from the [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/world-africa-50090691)

Non riesco a trovare un modo per tradurre quest'espressione in italiano:

- Il [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-italian/other) non considera neanche questo lemma come verbo, e non menziona *othering*
- [Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-italian/othering) non menziona *other* come verbo, e traduce *othering* come "alterità", "diversità", "percezione come qualcosa di estraneo" che non mi sembrano valide traduzioni:
- - [**alterità**](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/alterita/) e **diversità** sono concetti intrinseci a una persona o a un gruppo, piuttosto che processi attivi attraverso cui queste persone vengono *rese* tali
- - **percezione come qualcosa di estraneo**, oltre a essere una spiegazione e non una traduzione, ugualmente maschera il processo
- - [**alienare**](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/alienare/) mi sembra avere un'accezione un po' diversa.

Forse [**estraniare**](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/estraniare/) ed **estraniamento**?

Comment: Temo che questa domanda sia un po' “opinion-based”... Comunque, se non si vuole inventare un neologismo (come “altrare” o qualcosa del genere: non che io lo stia consigliando!), effettivamente “estraniare” sembra abbastanza calzante. La definizione data dal [GDLI](https://www.gdli.it/) sembra persino più calzante di quella del Treccani: “Ren­dere  estraneo, far sembrare estraneo, alieno, indifferente; separare, dividere, dissociare” (https://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/5?seq=468).

Comment: Emarginare, discriminare?